MySql-Provider: Contains in Linq-Query failed
I'm trying to create a Linq query that should work with a Contains on a string list.
The following query works without errors with the SqlServer and PostgreSQL providers:
IEnumerable<string> listStringValues = listStringValues.Where ( x => x != null ).Select ( x => x.ToUpper () );

var query = _ctx.Invoices.Where ( x => ( x.FormatType.FormatTypeCode == FormatTypeCode.ER ||
                                             x.FormatType.FormatTypeCode == FormatTypeCode.AR ||
                                             x.FormatType.FormatTypeCode == FormatTypeCode.EA ||
                                             x.FormatType.FormatTypeCode == FormatTypeCode.AA ) &&
listStringValues.Any ( y => y.Contains ( x.ExternalNumber.ToUpper () ) ) );                                 

Now my problem is that when I use this query with the MySql provider (Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql (8.0.2)), the following error message appears:
The LINQ expression '[Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ParameterQueryRootExpression]' could not be translated. Additional information: Primitive collections support has not been enabled. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
Do you have any tips for me on how to restructure the query so that you don't have to go through the detour of first loading all invoices based on the FormatTypeCode and then using LinqToObjects to filter them based on the listStringValues ​​list?
I tried to split the query and I also tried the way, that I at first load all the Invoices and executes the filter via Contains through LinqToObjects, which worked!

Are you sure this is the right approach? string.Contains should be translated to LIKE %MyValue%. And this type of query is difficult to index, and will likely cause a full table scan.

It may of course be that this is not the best approach, but this query works with the SqlServer and Postgresql provider (with this one query), I just wanted to know how to do it with MySql?

I have no idea how to write this for MySQL, but if nothing else work you could try writing the SQL by hand and use .FromSql to run it. ToQueryString might also be useful. Just make sure to test with a suitably large database to avoid nasty surprises in production.

When I try this, then it also works with MySql:
var query = _ctx.Invoices.Where ( x => ( x.FormatType.FormatTypeCode == FormatTypeCode.ER ||
                                         x.FormatType.FormatTypeCode == FormatTypeCode.AR ||
                                         x.FormatType.FormatTypeCode == FormatTypeCode.EA ||
                                         x.FormatType.FormatTypeCode == FormatTypeCode.AA ) );

var objs = query.AsEnumerable ();

var filteredList = objs.Where ( x => listStringValues .Any ( y => y.Contains ( x.ExternalNumber.ToUpper() ) ) ).ToList();

But with this solution I get at first all Invoices from the database into memory and after that I filter my Collection with the Contains of the listStringValues.
Best Regards
SB

This should be an addition to your question. It's not an answer.
